# Can we pass java method to to kotlin function of type () -> Unit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a method of kotlin like below

```
 fun initDrawer(drawerView: DrawerView, drawerLayout: DrawerLayout, context: Context, onRefreshClick: ()  -> Unit) {
  }
```

But when I try to pass initDrawer(drawerView,drawerlayout,this,onRefreshClick())
it gives me an error of required () cannot be applied to(kotlin.Unit)

is it possible to pass methods from java to kotlin.

Comment: I believe [this issue explains your situation](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FKT-12455).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to set return value of your onRefreshClick to Unit:

```
private Unit onRefreshClick() {
    //do something here
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
initDrawer(drawerView, drawerLayout, this, this::onRefreshClick);
```

Comment: () -> Unit is a function (lambda) that returns Unit. Unit onRefreshClick() { } is what you need.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot pass your Java method directly from Java, as the Kotlin parameter expects the method to return `Unit`.

You can follow the following pattern:

```
kotlinClass.higherOrderFunction(() -> {functionToPass(); return Unit.INSTANCE;});
```

where `functionToPass()` is defined as:

```
private void functionToPass() {
    // do something
}
```

In your case:

```
initDrawer(drawerView, drawerlayout, this, 
  () -> {onRefreshClick(); return Unit.INSTANCE;})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your Java method resides in a class called Test:

```
public class Test {
    void onRefreshClick() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

It could be called by your Kotlin function like this (as reference):

```
val t = Test()
initDrawer(drawerView, drawerlayout, this, t::onRefreshClick)
```

`onRefreshClick` could also be static in Java which would enable you to use it like this:

```
initDrawer(drawerView, drawerlayout, this, Test::onRefreshClick)
```

**Note:**
In Kotlin `() -> Unit` is the type of a function which has no arguments and returns nothing (which is `Unit` and not `Nothing` as return type).

There is no `Unit` in Java. The Java method which corresponds to this type would have no arguments and as return type `void`.

Comment: onRefreshClick() is java method