# How to pass callback function from Java to Kotlin class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, callback

I have a Kotlin class as follows (this is a sample for ease, hence it doesn't 'do' anything useful)

```
class MyKotlinClass (private val handleSomeCallBack: (ByteArray) -> Unit) {
    private val someBuffer = BytesBuilder()

    fun myFunction(bytesList: List<Byte>) {
        handleSomeCallBack(someBuffer.toArray())
    }
}
```

I want to call this code from a java class, hence, in that class I have the following declared:

```
public MyJavaClass() {
    messageParser = new MyClass(handleSomeCallback);
}
```

The callback method being passed is:

```
private void handleSomeCallback(byte[] dataBytes) {

}
```

(MyClass is correctly declared within the file)

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to pass the callback to the constructor of MyKotlinClass.

I have tried a variety of things including

`messageParser = new MyClass(handleSomeCallback(byte[] dataBytes));`

`messageParser = new MyClass(this::handleSomeCallback(byte[] dataBytes));`

But no matter what I try I receive an error.

I believe the answer is to do with lambdas but I can't quite see what the syntax should be for calling this from Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897764/can-we-pass-java-method-to-to-kotlin-function-of-type-unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with something like this:

```
MyKotlinClass instance = new MyKotlinClass(byteArray -> {
    // your code
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Or use `Unit` as return type of your separate method like suggested by @ADM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49897928/2910520)

You just need to add

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

to your `android` block in app `build.gradle`

Comment: Hey @MatPag - Thank you for your help with this. :)